# ERPNext cannot click into Allow Zero Valuation Rate button

Tags: inventory-management, erpnext

I set up the ERPNext system for my business to manage the inventory. My intention is to solely manage the quantity of my inventory. Therefore, I set the Valuation Rate to zero (0). However, when I create a Stock Entry, the "Allow Zero Valuation Rate" button is disabled, and I am unable to click it. Consequently, the Stock Entry ticket cannot be submitted.

Could you please advise on what might be causing this issue? I have tried allowing zero stock for all my items, but the problem persists.

Thank you.

[image]

[image]